# Connection Error while connecting SQL Server from KNIME using SQL Server connector in KNIME

Tags: sql-server, connectivity

We are trying to connect KNIME to SQL SErver, but getting an error :
Can someone help with the fix for this.

> Error : Establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure socket layer (SSL) encryption.

> Error : PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.sunCertapth BuilderException: unabe to find valid certification path to requested target".

[image]

Comment: There error seems to suggest an SSL issue. Have you verified the source and target are using compatible cypher suits?

Comment: Looks like the truststore is not configured correctly on the client.